# How to upload video/image to Linkedin through API with node?

Tags: node.js, file, axios, linkedin-api

I need to upload an image/video to Linkedin through API. I am using axios and have Content-Type set to multipart/form-data and all my images/videos that need to be uploaded are stored with a url to the file. All files are stored remotely on cloudinary.

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append(
  "fileupload",
  request(file.url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("video.mp4"))
);
axios
  .post("https://api.linkedin.com/media/upload", bodyFormData, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + account.accessToken,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  })
  .then(linkedinImageResult => {
```

I am following this documentation here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares#

One of the common errors I have gotten is: 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: source.pause is not a function

If I change

```
request(file.url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("video.mp4"))
```

to just

```
file.url
```

I get this error:
'java.io.IOException: Missing initial multi part boundary'

If I remove

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
```

I get this error:
"Unable to parse form content"

Note:
file.url is a url to a cloudinary file, example of file.url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dnc1t9z9o/video/upload/v1555527484/mn3tyjcpg1u4anlma2v7.mp4"

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Did you find a solution??

Comment: Not yet, but I will be looking into one again in the future. If you want this problem to attract more users, upvote my post :)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that using Rich Media is being [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares#post-rich-media-shares):

> Uploading image using https://api.linkedin.com/media/upload is being
> deprecated. Partners are recommended to use assets API that returns
> response such as urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ to post
> shares.

If you need help with the asset API, please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66109693/8727608)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this specific situation!

Here is my example code.

```
const postRichMedia = async (mediaURL, accessToken, fileName) => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  const key = S3Service.getSocialKeyFromUrl(mediaURL);
  const file = await S3Service.downloadFileFromS3(key);

  formData.append("fileupload", file.Body, fileName);

  try {
    const {data} = await axios.post('https://api.linkedin.com/media/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        ...formData.getHeaders(),
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      },
    });

    const {location} = data;

    return location;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```